# Wordpress next/prev links Issue

Tags: next-post-link, previous-post-link

```
previous_post_link(); 
next_post_link();
```

this code should display previous link and then next link , its showing totally opposite , is this wordpress issue or this is something me doing wrong

Answer (score 3):

From [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) (emphasis mine):

> In standard usage (within the default, unaltered loop) next_post_link
>   will generate a link to a post that is **newer** (more recent) than the
>   current post. This is in contrary to the similarly-named
>   previous_posts_link, which will typically link to a page of posts that
>   is **older** than the current batch.

It sounds like you just have different expectations about what "next" and "previous" means (I think if you asked me I would've guessed the opposite of this too).

If your - or more importantly, your readers' - conception of what next and previous means is different, then just swap the order of the links and change the labels to the opposite:

```
<?php next_post_link( '« %link' ); ?> | <?php previous_post_link( '%link »' ); ?>
```

Comment: I just did this but for a logic ,I wanted to make it clear .Thanks to making me things clear